# All the values in a list are changed to the newly appended value. What is the error here?

Tags: python, list, append

```
    x = []
    p = []
    n = int(input())
    for _ in range(n):
        cmd = input().split()
        if cmd[0] == "insert":
            x.insert(int(cmd[1]), int(cmd[2]))
        elif cmd[0] == "print":
            p.append(x)
        elif cmd[0] == "remove":
            x.remove(int(cmd[1]))
        elif cmd[0] == "append":
            x.append(int(cmd[1]))
        elif cmd[0] == "sort":
            x.sort()
        elif cmd[0] == "pop":
            x.pop()
        elif cmd[0] == "reverse":
            x.reverse()

    for i in p:
        print(i)
```

In python 3.7, for an input:

```
>     12
>     insert 0 5
>     insert 1 10
>     insert 0 6
>     print
>     remove 6
>     append 9
>     append 1
>     sort
>     print
>     pop
>     reverse
>     print
```

It is supposed to give the output:

> [6, 5, 10] 
>   [1, 5, 9, 10]
>   [9, 5, 1]

But, It's giving:

[9, 5, 1]  [9, 5, 1]  [9, 5, 1]

Please find the error in the code

Comment: You're appending the same `list` referred to by the name`x` 3 times.

Answer (score 1):

`append` does not make a copy. You want something like

```
p.append(x[:])
```

to add a "snapshot" of `x` to the list.

Answer (score 1):

`x` is a name reference to the `list` object you are modifying with each command.  It doesn't stop changing just because you added it to `p`.

Instead, you can insert a *copy* of `x` into `p` using slicing or `list.copy`:

```
elif cmd[0] == "print":
    p.append(x[:])
    # or use copy
    p.append(x.copy())
```